# Easier way to access the OSX defaults system through Python and Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, macos

Recently I have become a fan of storing various settings used for my testing scripts in the OSX [defaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) system as it allows me to keep various scripts in git and push them to github without worrying about leaving passwords/settings/etc hardcoded into the script.

When writing a shell script using simple bash commands, it is easy enough to use backticks to call the defaults binary to read the preferences and if there is an error reading the preference, the script stops execution and you can see the error and fix it. When I try to do a similar thing in Python or Ruby it tends to be a little more annoying since you have to do additional work to check the return code of defaults to see if there is an error.

I have been attempting to search via google off and on for a library to use the OSX defaults system which ends up being somewhat difficult when "defaults" is part of your query string.

I thought of trying to read the plist files directly but it seems like the plist libraries I have found (such as the built in python one) are only able to read the XML ones (not the binary ones) which is a problem if I ever set anything with the defaults program since it will convert it back to a binary plist.

Recently while trying another search for a Python library I changed the search terms to something using something like NSUserDefaults (I have now forgotten the exact term) I found a Python library called [userdefaults](http://sarwat.net/opensource/) but it was developed for an older version of OSX (10.2) with an older version of Python (2.3) and I have not had much luck in getting it to compile on OSX 10.6 and Python 2.6

Ideally I would like to find a library that would make it easy to read from (and as a bonus write to) the OSX defaults system in a way similar to the following python psudo code.

```
from some.library.defaults import defaults
settings = defaults('com.example.app')
print settings['setting_key']
```

Since I am also starting to use Ruby more, I would also like to find a Ruby library with similar functionality.

It may be that I have to eventually just 'give up' and write my own simple library around the defaults binary but I thought it wouldn't hurt to try to query others to see if there was an existing solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You´ll want to use PyObjC: have a look at [this article at mactech.com](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.25/25.09/2509MacintheShell/index.html) (in specific: scroll down to "Accessing plists Via Python"). And [this article from oreilly](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mac/2003/01/31/pyobjc_one.html) on PyObjC.
Run this, for example:

```
from Foundation import *
standardUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
persistentDomains = standardUserDefaults.persistentDomainNames()
persistentDomains.objectAtIndex_(14)
aDomain = standardUserDefaults.persistentDomainForName_(persistentDomains[14])
aDomain.keys()
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I'll need to test that out this weekend.